# Multiple drop downs, each one dependent on the value selected in the previous one. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop a filtering component consisting of 3 drop downs. The first one will fetch all the data from the db, the second one will fetch the data based on the selection from the first dropdown and the third one will fetch data based on the value selected in the second dropdown.

My problem is the following: whenever I select a value in the first or second dropdown, the values fetched for the next dropdown are one step behind.

Below is my code: I use an initial useEffect without parameters to set the first's dropdown's values, then I use 2 similar useEffects to look up at the selected values from the dropdowns.

```
useEffect(() => {

PostReqDevState.map((entry,index) => {

  if( projectNames.indexOf(entry["Requirement Submit-Project Name"]) === -1 && entry["Requirement Submit-Product Domain"] == personName.slice(-1)[0])
{
  console.log(entry["Requirement Submit-Product Domain"],entry["Requirement Submit-Project Name"])
  projectNames= [...projectNames,entry["Requirement Submit-Project Name"]]
}  
})

},[personName])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I used a temporary array to store the values which coresponded to the filters and I set a state(projectNames) with the values of the array.